# Storm fieldsgrouping lost tuples when one machine is down and the bolt is transferred to another machine

Tags: apache-storm

I have a bolt to process the data in filedGrouping way from a spout in storm . And one day one machine was down, the bolt was transfered to another machine automatically. In filedGrouping  way , some tuples from the spout will not be processed by any bolt . How can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use acking, the tuples that are lost should be retried by the spout.